# PHP - PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_connect' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying for the past couple days to establish  a connection to a MySQL db. I keep getting this error : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_connect' (T_STRING). This is all of the code in the script currently. I can't find the reason for the error.

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "database";

$c =  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

So, the issue was with an invisible Unicode character. I had copy pasted some of the code from another site. Resolved by re-entering manually. Thanks to the person who mentioned this, it looks like their answer was removed. I would have never figured this out. Thanks

Comment: i dont see how you can get that error, from this code, are you sure its the right code?

Comment: I would bet one of those variable stings actually has a character that needs escaping

Answer (score -3):

Below should help :)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($host,  $user,  $pass));
((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . $db)) or die('offline');
```

Comment: help how? do you even understand the error?

Comment: Use the code I gave in replacement of what you had, the issue is mysqli_connect is a function in PhP. You are treating it as a variable.

Comment: the issue is noting to do with mysql at all.

Answer (score -4):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

usually means you have a bad string somewhere on that line.

Comment: CAn reproduce, if I remove the "=" :)
$c   mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);